# Как найти, каким участком кода генерируется высота блока слайдера?

Tags: html, вёрстка

[Сайт](http://kamin-vogon.com), интересует вот эта строка index.html:

```html
<div class="tp-banner revslider-initialised tp-simpleresponsive hovered" id="revslider-258" style="height: 558px;">
```

А именно каким участком кода генерируется высота (в даном случае `height: 558px`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это revolutionslider весь код прописан в этом скрипте `js/revolutionslider/rs-plugin/js/custom.js` вот код

```
revapi = jQuery('.tp-banner').revolution(
        {
            delay:9000,
            startwidth:1170,
            startheight: window.screen.height>768?792:558,
            hideThumbs:10,
        });
```

в этой строке в зависимости от стартового положения дива с этим класом `tp-banner` выбирается высота слайдера собственно вот `window.screen.height>768?792:558`

Comment: Я уже поменял startheight. Просто думал, что высота 558px вычисляется каким-то другим скриптом. Не понимаю почему Chrome Dev Tools при выборе разрешения 1920*1080 не растягивает слайдер на 792px вместо 558px?